# Arithmetic operations for groups within a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have loaded multiple CSV (time series) to create one dataframe. This dataframe contains data for multiple stocks. Now I want to calculate 1 month return for all the datapoints.

There 172 datapoints for each stock i.e. from index 0 to 171. The time series for next stock starts from index 0 again.

When I am trying to calculate the 1 month return its getting calculated correctly for all data points except for index 0 of new stock. Because it is taking the difference with index 171 of the previous stock.

I want the return to be calculated per stock name basis so I tried the for loop but it doesnt seem working.

e.g. In the attached image (highlighted) the 1 month return is calculated for company name ITC with SHREECEM. I expect for SHREECEM the first value of 1Mreturn should be NaN

[image: refernce image]

Comment: Why don't you reset the index of your merged dataframe?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing samples of your input dataframes and expected output so that we can better understand what you're trying to do. Please [do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: To apply calculations per group, look up [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Answer (score 1):

Using groupby instead of a for loop you can get the result you want:

```
Mreturn_function = lambda df: df['mean_price'].diff(periods=1)/df['mean_price'].shift(1)*100
gw_stocks.groupby('CompanyName').apply(Mreturn_function)
```

Comment: Great Thanks ! It worked. I got the syntax error as the function can not start with a number changed that.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please vote up and accept as solution. This way future readers can find the right answer easier.